# Relationship returns null for some records - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

I have 2 models: TopHistory and User I using UUID for id column in User table, and `user_id` column in TopHistory. In TopHistory model. I have create a relationship method.

```
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id', 'id');
    }
```

I have 4 user and 4 history records. Each history record, I use `$user->id` itself to add the `user_id` field. And I try `return TopHistory::with('user')->get()`. But only 3 record return user data. Just have one record return null. I am sure the `user_id` field values of the 4 history records all exist user. Someone please help me solve this. Thanks

Comment: So focus on that 4th record that isn't showing the relation. Show the uuid of tophistory and of user model. Show dd() of the query you're doing, etc

Comment: This's a example:
`$request = RequestInstallApp::where('id', '43')->with(['app', 'user'])->first();`
// It's will be return user null here. And now i use 
`$request['user'] = User::find($request->user_id);`
// So it's work